# How to run code snippet at breakpoint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

In Eclipse (Java), I can hold the execution at a breakpoint and run a code snippet in the execution environment. This is called [Display view](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/display/ref-display_view.htm)

Is there a way to do this in RubyMine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes rubymine support debugging. More info at http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/features/ruby_debugger.html

In rubymine the option is called "Evaluate Expression". Its gets activated once the execution his the breakpoint similar to eclipse.